# Google TV : is there a way to know the current channel/program being watched with user permission?

Tags: android, google-tv

**in an android application :**
Is there an interface defined in android to support this query ?

I've searched a lot on this, but was unable to find more info.
This seems like a fairly reasonable query(provided user permission is granted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible do to many restrictions - if you were to write an application that managed the user channel changes then you could access the Channel Lineup on the GTV and then it would be possible to know what channel they are on. If however you want to just arbitrarily know what the user has currently tuned to this is not possible - mainly because the user could have used their cable box remote to change the channel and as such the data is not available to the GTV unit.